# How to connect GtkModelButton

Tags: button, builder, gnome, vala

Helo,

I've got the following .ui file:

```
<child>
  <object class="GtkModelButton" id="button_neworder">
    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
    <property name="text" translatable="yes">Neuer Auftrag</property>
    <property name="action-name">?</property>
    <property name="visible">True</property>
  </object>
</child>
```

And the following ApplicationWindow:

```
public class Window : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {
    [GtkChild]

    private unowned Gtk.ListBox listbox_jobs;
    private unowned Gtk.Button button_neworder;

    public Window (Gtk.Application app) {
        Object (application: app, title: "Auftragsverwaltung");
        this.button_neworder.clicked.connect(this.method);
    }

    public void method() {
    }
}
```

How can I create a clicked signal with GtkModelButton?

The code

```
this.button_neworder.clicked.connect(this.method);
```

doesnt work.

Comment: I have not personally used .ui files, but you might try moving the signal connection to the `construct` block in your `Window` class. The `button_neworder` button might not be instantiated at the time you're trying to connect the signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your signal to the .ui file with `<signal/>`:

```vala
...
<child>
  <object class="GtkModelButton" id="button_neworder">
    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
    <property name="text" translatable="yes">Neuer Auftrag</property>
    <property name="action-name">?</property>
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <signal name="clicked" handler="button_neworder_clicked" />
  </object>
</child>
...
```

and identify the method as a callback with `[GtkCallback]`:

```vala
[GtkTemplate(ui = "/template/window.ui")]
public class Window : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {
    [GtkChild]

    private unowned Gtk.ListBox listbox_jobs;
    private unowned Gtk.Button button_neworder;

    public Window (Gtk.Application app) {
        Object (application: app, title: "Auftragsverwaltung");
        this.button_neworder.clicked.connect(this.method);
    }

    [GtkCallback]
    public void button_neworder_clicked(Gtk.ModelButton button) {
    }
}
```